# Unable to render index.html file from my view folder in angular2

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm creating a MEAN Stack application where angular has setup in `/client` folder. I want that when I run `npm start` command in `/client` folder it should render `index.html` file from `/views` folder, what I'm doing wrong getting this error

`Cannot GET /`

Folder structure is as follows.

meanApp

----- client (angluar2 setup here but doesn't have an index.html file)

---------- app

----- views

----------index.html

----- routes

----- server.js

Codes in server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var index =  require('./routes/index');
var tasks = require("./routes/tasks");

var app = express();

//View engines

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname,'views'));

app.set("view engine", 'ejs');

app.engine("html", require("ejs").renderFile);

//Set static folder

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'client')));

// Body parser

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.use('/', index);

app.use('/index', index);

app.use('/api', tasks);

//listen

app.listen(3000, function(){

    console.log("Server listing @ 3000");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to define route for express server like :

```
app.set('appPath', 'client'); //this is a folder where your index.html is

app.route('/*')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      res.sendfile(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html');
    });
```

This will cause every call in broweser to render index file.

Answer (score 0):

```
const http = require('http');
fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var app = express();

app.set('appPath', 'views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(expressValidator());

app.use('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendfile(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3001, function() {
    console.log(`Express server listening on port 3001`);
});

exports = module.exports = app;
```